# div id contains length is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am checking `Div` id contains. If that Div exists show show another div to show or hide.

If I use full div id length is showing 1 else always zero.

```
$(function () {
  alert($('div[id="dnn_ctr2555_DNNWebControlContainer_ctl01_SPE_MBRDemographicsControl_pnlDemographics"]').length);
  if ($('div[id^="_SPE_MBRDemographicsControl_pnlDemographics"]').length) {
    /* it exists */
    $('#DemographicCntrlContent').show();
  }
  else {
    /* it doesn't exist */
    $('#DemographicCntrlContent').hide();
  }
})
```

what wrong in my if condition.

Comment: `^=` is "begins with" - you probably meant `$=` which is ends with

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: @j08691 - why? the question is clear enough

Comment: @JaromandaX - Because I'd like to see one.

Comment: I would try the `*=` or  `~=` and not the `^=`.

Comment: `~=` would not work in this case

Comment: All that's said, cannot you use class instead?

Comment: @A.Wolff - you've never worked with DNN?

Comment: @JaromandaX good point and no i didnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[attr^=abc]` checks for attribute that **begins with** `abc`

`[attr$=abc]` checks for attribute that **ends with** `abc`

`[attr*=abc]` checks for attribute that **contains the string** `abc`

`[attr~=abc]` checks for attribute that **is equal to** `abc` - so `hello abcd` wont match, but `hello abc` will

`[attr|=abc]` checks for attribute that **is** `abc` or `abc-...` i.e. the exact word `abc` or `abc` followed by `-` (then followed by anything)

Comment: Your last definition isnt completly accurate

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of removing that until I find the definitive wording

Comment: @A.Wolff - I think that's better now

Comment: I'm almost ashamed to say where that wrong definition came from ... starts with w3 and ends with schools - I knew I should've looked elsewhere :p

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `carat(^)` symbol which basically means 'starts with'. If you wish to look for contains , you can use `div[id*=`.

```
if ($('div[id*=""]').length)
```

Another way of checking this is through `.contains()` selector:

```
if($("div").attr("id").contains('_SPE_MBRDemographicsControl_pnlDemographics')) // return true - false
```